# Javascript regex positive less than 10000 than can be decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, decimal

I need a regex for a number than can be decimal and less than 10000 with max 2 digits after decimal. 
I tried

```
/^([0-9]{1,4})+(\.[0-9]{0,2})$/
```

but it returns true for 44555.54 for example.

Comment: `^[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` or `^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$`

Comment: My idea: `^[0-9]{1,4}\.?[0-9]{0,2}$` (https://regex101.com/r/Ml1VY0/1)

Comment: @EganWolf : it would be true for 6 digits

Comment: `1000` in title and `10000` in question

Comment: @PranavCBalan You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex you are using `+` which is using for one or more repetition and which leads to match any length of digit and make decimal part non-greedy(using`?`) to make it optional.

```
^[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

or using `\d` for digit character class.

```
^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$
```